# how to replace all special characters except underscore and period in php?

Tags: php, regex

Can any one please show me how i can replace all special characters in a string except the underscore and the period symbols.And also I've been trying to understand how to make this replace patterns reading the `PHP` manual and its so confusing for a beginner like me so is there any other documentation or tutorial that is made easy for beginners so that i don't have to post another question like this and trouble you people every time i want to use this function?

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $string);
```

this is what i have it replaces all the special characters but i want to except `_` and  `.`.

Comment: [Read up on regular expressions here!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Put `_` and `.` to the negated set of characters (`[^...]`):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.]/', '', $string);
```

You should not omit `$string = ..` because `preg_replace` return replaced string. It does not change the string in place.

Comment: @maniteja, FYI, Above pattern could be replaced with `/[^\w.]/` because `\w` match any word character (including alphabets, digits, `_`).

Comment: How would you allow for the '/' character here?

Comment: @ChrisSchlitt, Add `/`, with proper escape: `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9_.\/]/'`. Or using another regex delimeter (without escape): `'|[^a-zA-Z0-9_./]|'`

Comment: @ChrisSchlitt, how to replace all special characters except `,` and  `/`

Answer (score 1):

You  can  use some php filter widget like Purifier (to set a whitelist for input)...

But Still,  we  would  like to suggest  you  to  learn regex!